# How to detect clicks on disabled elements in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on a Jetpack Compose project where I need to detect clicks on disabled elements to provide users with the reason why they cannot perform the action. Here's an example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DisabledClickableElement(isEnabled: Boolean) {
    Button(
        enabled = isEnabled,
        onClick = {
            // Handle click action
            if (isEnabled) {
                // Perform the action
                // ...
            } else {
                // Explain why the action is disabled
                showSnackBar("You cannot do that because...")
            }
        }
    ) {
        Text("Click me!")
    }
}
```

However, the `onClick` listener only works when the `enabled` parameter is set to `true`. How can I detect clicks on disabled elements, but still maintain their disabled look and accessibility features?

Answer (score 1):

After disabling the button, `onClick` of the `Button` will not work. If you add a `Box` within the `Button` and give the `onClick` event to the `Box`, you can preserve the disabled appearance of the button and the `.clicable` feature will work.

```
@Composable
fun DisabledClickableElement(isEnabled: Boolean) {
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(48.dp)
            .width(200.dp),
        enabled = isEnabled,
        onClick = {

        },
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(),
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .clickable {
                    // Handle click action
                    if (isEnabled) {
                        // Perform the action
                        // ...
                    } else {
                        // Explain why the action is disabled
                        showSnackBar("You cannot do that because...")
                    }
                },
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Click me!",
            )
        }
    }
}
```